# Gmail app only shows "Archive" button for one account

Tags: gmail

I have two gmail accounts connected on my HTC Incredible.  When looking at account 1, I can select some emails and three buttons appear: Archive, Delete, and Labels.  But when using account 2 and an email is selected, only Delete and Label buttons appear.  How can I get the "Archive" button to appear in the second account?

Comment: Are these both the same type of GMail account? Is one normal GMail, and the other Google Apps GMail maybe? Also what version of Android are you running? If you're on 2.2 have you downloaded the updated Gmail from the Market to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: This is weird! I have a 'normal' and Google Apps account on mine and can see all the options fine. +1 check you have updated Gmail from the Market, various other bugs fixed so maybe this too.

Comment: These are both normal Gmail accounts.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Upgrade to the new Gmail released 3 days ago and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be working fine now.  Even before the upgrade, it worked intermittently.  But since the upgrade, it seems to be solid.  Running version 2.3.2.